# Adding together totals of 2 different tables

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word 2010, can you add a total of one table together with the total of another table to create a grand total in the 2nd table?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you know the exact addresses of the cells you need to total, or the addresses of the cells that contain each table's total.

Let's say you have Table 1 with

```
1   2   3   { =SUM(LEFT) }
4   5   6   { =SUM(LEFT) }
            { =SUM(ABOVE) }
```

and Table 2 with

```
7   8   9   { =SUM(LEFT) }
10  11  12  { =SUM(LEFT) }
            { = SUM(ABOVE) }
            You want the totals here in cell D4!
```

Then what you do is

- Select Table 1
- Use Insert->Bookmark to insert a bookmark (let's call it Table1)
- Notice that you want either the sum of A1:C2 or the value of D3 from
  Table 1 and either the sum of A1:C2 or the value of D3 from table 2
- In table 2, cell D4, insert the following field code (use ctrl-F9 to
  insert the special field code braces { })

  { =SUM(Table1 A1:C2,A1:C2) }
- or any of the following...

  { =SUM(Table1 D3:D3,A1:C2) }

  { =SUM(Table1 D3:D3,D3) }

  { =SUM(Table1 A1:C2,D3) }